# sprintf() for JavaScript that behaves like Python's format (%)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printf

I need a JavaScript function (or jQuery plugin) for `printf`/`sprintf`. It needs to support named arguments (`"%(foo)s"`) and padding (`"%02d"`), *i.e.* the following format string should work:

```
"%(amount)s.%(subunits)02d"
```

It only needs to support `s` and `d`, I don't care about all the other format strings (e.g. `f`, `x`, etc.). I don't need padding for strings/`s`, just `d`, I only need simple padding for `d`, e.g. `%2d`, `%3d`, `%04d`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A previous question "[Javascript printf/string.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-printf-string-format)" has some good information.

Also, dive.into.javascript() has [a page](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf) about `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

The PHPJS project has implemented a lot of PHP's functionality in Javascript. I can't imagine why they'd want to do that, but the fact remains that they have produced a `sprintf()` implementation which should satisfy your needs (or at least come close).

Code for it can be found here: http://phpjs.org/functions/sprintf

Answer (score 2):

Here one function

```js
var sprintf = function(str) {
  var args = arguments,
    flag = true,
    i = 1;

  str = str.replace(/%s/g, function() {
    var arg = args[i++];

    if (typeof arg === 'undefined') {
      flag = false;
      return '';
    }
    return arg;
  });
  return flag ? str : '';
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  var msg = 'the department';

  $('#txt').html(sprintf('<span>Teamwork in </span> <strong>%s</strong>', msg));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center id="txt"></center>
```